# Paragraphs Entity Type Causing Issues After Core Update

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am getting this error whenever I try to create a node on Drupal 8.6.2.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The paragraph entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager line 133.

Right now, the paragraphs module is turned off. I have ran `drupal updb` to see if the database needed updating; nothing came back.

I tried `drupal moi` and `drupal mou` for paragraphs, but I get this error.

> [ERROR] Configuration objects (core.entity_view_mode.paragraph.preview) provided by paragraphs already exist in active configuration

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out, not sure if it is the best way, I ended up using a mysql command to delete the config manually:

```
DELETE FROM `config` WHERE name='core.entity_view_mode.paragraph.preview';
```

After, you can enable and disable the module. Which appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed Drush, you can use the following command to delete the configuration object from the database.

```
drush cdel core.entity_view_mode.paragraph.preview
```

Comment: This looks like the same solution above only as a Drush command. In which case, that answer should be amended to have both.

Comment: While the commands obtain the same effect, these are two different answers.